# Cannot convert call result type '_?' to expected type '[UInt]'

Tags: swift, swift2

```
self.mapper.identityIdsForQuickbloxUserIds(userIDs.map{($0 as! NSNumber).unsignedLongValue}, completion: { identityIdsMapping, error in
```

> Cannot convert call result type '_?' to expected type '[UInt]'

`userIDs` is `NSSet`

and here is a function:

```
func identityIdsForQuickbloxUserIds(userIds:[UInt], completion:(identityIdsMapping:[UInt: String]?, error:NSError?) -> Void)
```

how to convert it in a right way?

This is external function which return for me that set:

```
- (void)allDialogsWithPageLimit:(NSUInteger)limit
                extendedRequest:(QB_NULLABLE NSDictionary *)extendedRequest
                 iterationBlock:(void(^QB_NULLABLE_S )(QBResponse *QB_NONNULL_S response, NSArray QB_GENERIC(QBChatDialog *) *QB_NULLABLE_S dialogObjects, NSSet QB_GENERIC(NSNumber *) * QB_NULLABLE_S dialogsUsersIDs, BOOL * QB_NONNULL_S stop))iterationBlock
                     completion:(void(^QB_NULLABLE_S)(QBResponse * QB_NONNULL_S response))completion;
```

As you see we got that NSSet from here:

```
NSSet QB_GENERIC(NSNumber *) * QB_NULLABLE_S dialogsUsersIDs
```

that method is from [QuickBlox SDK](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-services-ios/blob/c32eddd73cc3b5cc3481610ff0f04b6fbade97e8/QMChatService/QMChatService/QMChatService.h)

Comment: i have tried this "let userIds = NSSet(objects: 1, 2, 3).map{($0 as! NSNumber).unsignedLongValue}" and work just fine. Are you sure you're not trying to map an object? If so the $0 won't work.

Comment: The problem isn't clear in what you've posted, needs more details. Perhaps isolate the map method to confirm the problem's happening there.  And double check the data in your NSSet can be type cast to NSNumber, I suspect the problem's there.

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1:**

Here is a simple example:

```
    identityIdsForQuickbloxUserIds([1,2,3]) { dictionary, error in


    }
```

**Example 2:**

```
    let x = NSSet(array: [1, 2, 3]).map { $0 as! UInt }

    identityIdsForQuickbloxUserIds(x) { dictionary, error in


    }
```

Comment: sorry, it is difficult to understand your question. Which piece of code throws the error ? Paste the error and all the relevant code (just the bare minimum) so that it is possible to run it and test it

Answer (score 1):

`userIDs` is optional `Set<NSNumber>?` not `Set<NSNumber>` so you need unwrap if first with something like this

```
var ids = userIDs?.map { $0.unsignedLongValue } ?? [UInt]()

...

identityIdsForQuickbloxUserIds(ids, ...)
```

Comment: Makes sense. @Matrosov Alexander could you paste the declaration of `userIDs`